# String match in sliding window

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, trie

Lets say you have a file which has the following string

```
a a a b a a b a a b b a b
```

You don't have access to the file but a function FetchNextChar() that gives one character at a time.

and the pattern to match is  `a a b`

How would you count the total number of hits?

Here is what I am thinking.

1. If the character fetched is the first char of pattern ('a') then add it to a Queue
2. Start appending/create a linked list for next char if it matches with next char of pattern

So after 1st fetch we have

```
Pattern -a 
Queue - a 

Then 

Pattern -a  a 
Queue[0] a->a 
Queue[1] a


3rd 
Pattern    a    a    b
Queue[0]   a -->a--> a    //doesn't match, dequeue
Queue[1]        a-> a
Queue[2]             a
```

I think this would work but the issue I see is if there a multiple char's that match with the first char of pattern I would keep adding to the Queue and so keep increasing the list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not KMP algorithm ?

Comment: @Imposter Do [link to an algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KMP_algorithm) if you want to mention it.

Comment: This is a solved problem. Refer to Gusfield 1997. From a practical point of view the best algorithm to use is the Boyer-Moore algorithm.

Comment: What would be a good DS to efficiently store the TEXT from the file and slide the window? Ideally we would want to store only the length of the pattern in buffer to compare.

Comment: do you wish to only match `aab`, or is it just an example, and you would like to know a general algorithm to count any the number of occurences of any string on a stream of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved efficiently using [Rabin–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) calculating a `rolling hash` for the sliding window, a naive rolling hash function is to sum the ASCII code of the characters, but you can use this array of `primes` to make the collisions less, I've tested these primes and gave me few collisions on a big and alike string and pattern matching :

```
primes[] = {13 , 7963 , 17443 , 27527 , 37879 , 48673 , 59407 , 70729 , 81883 , 93251 , 104789 , 116531 , 128239 , 139969 , 151783 , 163883 , 176159 , 188029 , 200257 , 212447 , 224831 , 237283 , 249517 , 262217 , 274661 , 287173};
```

And here is the pseudo-code for the above algorithm to print the count of matches :

```
stream = "aaabaabaabbab";
pattern = "aab";
queue window;

patternHash = 0;
for ch in pattern:
    patternHash = patternHash + primes[ch - 'a']

first = readFromStream(stream)
window.enqueue(first)
windowHash = primes[first - 'a']
for i = 0 to pattern.size():
    ch = readFromStream(stream)
    window.enqueue(ch)
    windowHash = windowHash + primes[ch - 'a']

count = 0
for i = pattern.size() to stream.size():
    if windowHash == patternHash
        if window == pattern
            count = count + 1
    ch = readFromStream(stream)
    window.enqueue(ch)
    windowHash = windowHash - primes[window.first() - 'a']
    windowHash = windowHash + primes[ch - 'a']
    window.dequeue()

print count
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a state based algorithm:

[image: three state algorithm]

We can see that each time a `'b'` is read we go on `state=0` and the number of the pattern occurrence is increased by one if we were on `state=2`. When a `'a'` is read we go to the next state bounded by `state=2` obviously.

here a python script that implements the algorithm

```
stream = ['a','a','a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b','b','a','b']

state = 0 
nbMatch = 0

for c in stream:
    if c=='a':
        if state==0 or state==1:
            state = state+1
        #if state == 2: state=2
    else: #c=='b'
        if state==2:
            nbMatch = nbMatch+1
        state = 0
    print c, "   state=", state
print nbMatch
```